# Functions are not valid as a React child (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I can not wrap my head around and understand why am I given this warning, I am using two kinds of navigators ( tab navigator and stack navigator ), in App.js and I cannot seem to get them working correctly

***App.js***

```
export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
      'FormScreen': {
        screen: FormScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Contact Us',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="ios-contact" type="entypo" size={28} color={tintColor} />
        }
      },
      'ListScreen': {
        screen: ListScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel: 'Contact List',
          tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" type="entypo" size={28} color={tintColor} />
        }
      }
    });
    export const NavigationScreen = () => {
      return StackNavigator(
        {

          Tabs: {
            screen: Tabs,
            navigationOptions: {
              gesturesEnabled: false
            }
          }
        },
        {
          headerMode: "none",
          mode: "modal"
        }
      );
    };   
    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
         <NavigationScreen/>);
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can try ```export const NavigationScreen = StackNavigator({ ...```

Comment: This has actually worked, Can you explain why?

Comment: StackNavigator returns a `createNavigationContainer` which is a Higher Order Component to return a `NavigationContainer` class. Therefore rather than returning the function twice, you can directly bind it to a `const`

Comment: Alright, Thanks a lot !